# how to convert mm-dd-yyyy hh-mit-sec pm to yyyy-mm-dd date format

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

```
string dateRange ="and CONVERT(datetime, BreakDownStartDateTime) 
                   >= CONVERT(datetime, '" + startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "') 
                   and CONVERT(datetime, BreakdownEndDateTime)   
                   <= CONVERT(datetime, '" + endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "', 126";
```

startdate: `12/2/2013 12:52:45 PM`

enddate: `12/2/2013 12:52:45 PM`

Comment: Please use parameters instead - you can then pass native `DateTime` objects across which will be automatically converted to SQL `datetime`s and you don't have to touch anything to do with formatting - formatting issues only arise because **you** are forcing a conversion to strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you read the DateTime.ToString documentation that gives you the formats you can supply to get the date back in a specific format?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

so in your question, you want to convert to yyyy-mm-dd:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

converts the current date - with yours, you use startDate and endDate variables instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @D DATETIME = GETDATE();

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @D, 120) AS [YYYY-MM-DD]
```

Result

```
YYYY-MM-DD
2013-12-02
```

**OR**

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @D, 111), '/', '-') AS [YYYY-MM-DD]
```

Result

```
YYYY-MM-DD
2013-12-02
```